# du linux command size greater than df

Tags: linux, filesystems, embedded-linux, filesize

I am using Digi embedded linux module which is having 8MB flash and 16MB RAM.

My partition table is as below:

[image]

SO, I got 4.4MB for rootfs. And 2MB for UserFS.

When I run ‘df -ah’, I get following output.

[image]

However, when I run ‘du -sh’ on root, I have 4M in /lib and 3M in /usr. Both are under root. However, the root is only 4.4M.

I have checked for symbolic link and can confirm that the files are physically present on /lib and /usr.

[image]

I deleted some of the library files(*netsnmp*) under /lib, which was close to 2M, but the available size on /dev/root only increased by ~390K(from 408K to 792K).

[image]

This suggests that the /lib/libnetsnmp* were stored somewhere else. I am not sure where those files were saved. **Any ideas?**

Also, please note that the rootfs image size is 4M. And this is shown correctly in df -ah command on /dev/root filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

JFFS2 has transparent compression built in if I recall correctly. Executables compress pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

if the file is in use. you can't delete it really.
you can use `lsof | grep deleted` to find them.

Answer (score -1):

Probably it is due to the existence of hard-links in the root filesystem. Each hard-link will be shown as a normal file, but all hard-links will point to the same inode, so physically there is only one copy of the file in the hard-disk. You can see a good definition of soft-link and hard-link in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/801191/594951).

EDIT: You can search for hard-links using this command (taken from this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/201922/163241)):

```
find . -samefile /path/to/file
```

Comment: I believe it is not to do with links. the filenames in /lib are all lib*.so files. The filenames in /usr are all the mib files.

Comment: I don't think the hard-link is the reason. `du` won't count the hard-linked files twice or more.